# dial a number in Cisco IP Communicator with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, integration, phone-call, cisco

We are working on a custom CRM and we need to provide a functionality to allow make calls to our clients through a .NET application. Our company have Cisco IP Communicator like a telephone service to his contact center.

Anybody have some sample o tutorial to dial a number in Cisco IP Communicator through a (C#).NET application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i did with the SOAP SERVICE WebDialer provided by CISCO CALL MANAGER

https://IP:PORT/webdialer/services/WebdialerSoapService?wsdl

Comment: which PORT ? I have Cisco phone with IP